# Изменение значения ячейки в зависимости от значения ячейки с input

Tags: javascript, html

Привет всем.
Есть таблица товара с несколькими значениями. Цена берётся из ячейки с **class="price"**
Помимо этого есть ячейки с **display:none** и классами price_50, price_100, price_500, price_1000, price_2500
Необходимо реализовать так что бы при вводе в input количество >=50 цена бралась из ячейки с **class="price_50"**,
 при вводе >=100 из ячейки с **class="price_100"**,
при вводе >=500 из ячейки с **class="price_500"**,
при вводе >=1000 из ячейки с **class="price_1000"**,
при вводе >=2500 из ячейки с **class="price_2500"**
т.е. что бы цена менялась динамически в зависимости от введённого значения в ячейке "количество".
Так же те строки в которых значение ячейки "количесво" отлично от нуля необходимо вывести в `<p class="output-all"></p>` т.е вывести все ячейки данной строки в одну строку.
Всем заранее спасибо.
Пример таблицы
https://jsfiddle.net/v8wh4sLh/

Comment: Не понял про output-all. Можете подробней объяснить?

Comment: есть <p class="output-all"></p> в него надо вывести все строки со значением в input более 0, например так Товар > ЧАБ > АБС. Цвет: черный. > количество 5 > цена 99 > сумма 495

Comment: Можете показать пример кода того, что должно упасть в output-all?

Comment: И еще такой вопрос. Когда у нас количество от 50 до 100, то мы прячем ячейку с price и отображаем price_100?

Comment: Именно так, только не  price_100 а price_50

Comment: Так, понял. Сейчас напишу решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я позволил себе переделать некоторые вещи в структуре HTML и додумал некоторые вещи в JS, которые были не описаны.

Так будет меньше нагрузка на DOM и проще работать со значениями. Ну и расширять всё это дело тоже. В принципе, можно было разбить на более мелкие функции, но я не стал.

```js
var calculator = {
 parent: document.getElementById('table-price-box'),
 totalPrice: 0,
 position: [],
 isText: false,

 init: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.parent.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
   var field = e.target,
    tr = field.parentElement.parentElement;

   // Пересчитываем стоимость в этом поле
   self.changeInput(field, tr);

   // Пересчитываем всё
   self.recount();
  });
 },

 // Пересчет одного поля
 changeInput: function(field, tr) {
  var price = tr.querySelector('.price'),
   num = parseInt(field.value);

  // Если ввели не число, то ничего не меням
  if(!isNaN(num)) {
   var count = this.getCount(price, num),
    result;

   // Считаем итоговую цену
   result = count * num;

   // Если у нас в качестве цены за единицу текстовое значение, то не будем ничго выводить
   if(isNaN(result)) {
    tr.querySelector('.sum').textContent = '';
   }

   // В противном случае вывведем цену
   else {

    // Но сначала округляем число
    result = Math.round(result);

    // Выводим
    tr.querySelector('.sum').textContent = result;
   }

   // Меняем отображаемую стоимость за единицу
   price.textContent = count;
  }
 },

 // Получаем стоимость единицы товара в зависимости от позиции
 getCount: function(price, num) {
  var count;

  if(num < 50) count = price.dataset.price0;
  if(num >= 50 && num < 100) count = price.dataset.price50;
  if(num >= 100 && num < 500) count = price.dataset.price100;
  if(num >= 500 && num < 1000) count = price.dataset.price500;
  if(num >= 1000 && num < 2500) count = price.dataset.price1000;
  if(num >= 2500) count = price.dataset.price2500;

  return count;
 },

 // Пересчитываем весь калькулятор
 recount: function() {
  var self = this,
   tr = this.parent.querySelectorAll('tr');

  // Обнуляем общую сумму, позиции и текстовые суммы
  self.totalPrice = 0;
  self.positions = [];
  self.isText = false;

  tr.forEach(function(item) {
   var field = item.querySelector('input');

   // Проверяем есть ли в строке инпут
   if(field) {
    var num = field.value;

    // Дополниельно проверяем количество на "не число"
    if(!isNaN(num) && num > 0) {
     var price = item.querySelector('.price').textContent;

     // Проверяем есть ли у нас стоимость за единицу в значении
     if(isNaN(+price)) {
      self.isText = true;
     } else {
      // Увеличиваем общую стоимость
      self.totalPrice += parseFloat(item.querySelector('.sum').textContent);
     }

     // Добавляем позиции
     self.positions.push({
      classificator: item.querySelector('.calc-classificator').textContent,
      properties: item.querySelector('.calc-properties').textContent,
      price: price,
      num: num,
      sum: item.querySelector('.sum').textContent
     });

    }

   }

  });

  self.setNewResult();

 },


 // Устанавливаем новые результаты
 setNewResult: function() {
  var self = this,
   sum = self.totalPrice;

  // Если у нас есть текстовое значение, то добавляем плюсик
  if(self.isText) sum += '+';
  self.parent.querySelector('#total').textContent = sum;

  // Выводим добавленные позиции
  var str = '';
  self.positions.forEach(function(pos) {
   str += '<div style="margin-bottom: 5px">';
   str += 'Классификатор:' + pos.classificator + ' ';
   str += 'Свойства:' + pos.properties + ' ';
   str += 'Цена:' + pos.price + ' ';
   str += 'Кол-во:' + pos.num + ' ';
   str += 'Сумма:' + pos.sum + ' ';
   str += '</div>';
  });
  self.parent.querySelector('.output-all').innerHTML = str;
 }
};
calculator.init();
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table id="table-price-box" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p style="font-size:20px;margin:5px 0;">Общая сумма заказа <span id="total">0</span> руб</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p class="output-all"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="30%">
        <p align="center">Наименование</p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="10%">
        <p align="center">Классификатор материала</p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="30%">
        <p align="center">Основные свойства материала</p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="10%">
        <p align="center">Количество</p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="10%">
        <p align="center">Цена, руб</p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" width="10%">
        <p align="center">Итого, руб</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="td-box">
      <td align="center" rowspan="5" valign="middle"><a href="#">Товар</a><br/>
        <p>Габаритные размеры<br/>65x36x14 мм</p>
        <p align="center"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/99cccc.gif" class="price-img"/></p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" class="calc-classificator">ЧАБ</td>
      <td align="center" class="calc-properties">АБС. Цвет: черный.</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input min="0" type="number" style="border-radius:5px;width:80%;"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center" data-price0="99" data-price50="84" data-price100="74.6" data-price500="67.2" data-price1000="61.6" data-price2500="догов." class="price">99</td>
      <td align="center" class="sum"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="td-box">
      <td align="center" class="calc-classificator">
        ССА
        ТСА
      </td>
      <td align="center" class="calc-properties">АБС. Цвет: светло-серый; темно-серый.</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input min="0" type="number" style="border-radius:5px;width:80%;"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center" data-price0="106" data-price50="89.2" data-price100="79.4" data-price500="71.4" data-price1000="65.4" data-price2500="догов." class="price">106</td>
      <td align="center" class="sum"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="td-box">
      <td align="center" class="calc-classificator">ЧАББ</td>
      <td align="center" class="calc-properties">АБС с повышенным блеском. Цвет: черный.</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input min="0" type="number" style="border-radius:5px;width:80%;"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center" data-price0="102" data-price50="86.6" data-price100="77" data-price500="69.2" data-price1000="63.4" data-price2500="догов." class="price">102</td>
      <td align="center" class="sum"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="td-box">
      <td align="center" class="calc-classificator">
        ССАБ
        ТСАБ
      </td>
      <td align="center" class="calc-properties">АБС с повышенным блеском. Цвет: светло-серый; темно-серый.</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input min="0" type="number" style="border-radius:5px;width:80%;"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center" data-price0="104" data-price50="87.8" data-price100="78" data-price500="70.2" data-price1000="64.4" data-price2500="догов." class="price">104</td>
      <td align="center" class="sum"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="td-box">
      <td align="center" class="calc-classificator">Латунь</td>
      <td align="center" class="calc-properties">Покрытие - никель</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input min="0" type="number" style="border-radius:5px;width:80%;"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center" data-price0="54" data-price50="45.2" data-price100="40.2" data-price500="36.2" data-price1000="33.2" data-price2500="догов." class="price">54</td>
      <td align="center" class="sum"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Тут написано избегать комментариев в духе "спасибо", но я вас всё равно благодарю, сейчас я во хмелю и не могу протестировать ваше решение. Как доберусь до компьютера обязательно проверю и отпишусь. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Да, всё отлично работает, только у меня ещё пара вопросов. Как сделать что бы в output-all так же добавлялся текст ссылки(товар) из первого столбца? Можно ли сделать что бы output-all выводился не в таблице, а в произвольном месте на странице(привязаться не к class, а к id)